# (Geometry Nodes) Sample curve tangent with multiple splines

Tags: geometry-nodes

https://youtu.be/OXGD1KlSuZo

Aligning instances to a curve is great, UNTIL a second curve/spline is added. In which case it *instantly* goes to hell.  As much as I've searched, I can't seem to solve this (elementary) issue.

As it's fundamental to following input curves I know I *must* be doing something wrong? but I can't figure it out despite plentiful googling.  What am I missing here, or is it a bug ?

[image: single curve(spline)]
[image: Multiple Splines]
[image: basic geometry node]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your setup is that the *Sample Curve* node's output is based on the complete curve, which means the *Factor* or *Length* are accumulated to the total length of all curves, if you have multiple curves in your geometry.

For example, let's say your geometry holds two curves: the first has a length of 4 meters, the second a length of 6 meters. This means for the *Spline Parameter* node:

- The first curve has a length of 0 meters and a factor of 0 at its starting point and a length of 4 meters and a factor of 1 at its end point.
- The second curve has 0 meters and factor 0 at the start and 6 meters and factor 1 at the end.

If you now use a *Sample Curve* node this accumulates all curves to treat them as one curve which results in the following values:

- The overall curve has a length of 10 meters, with factor 0 at the start of the first curve and factor 1 at the end of the last curve.
- The first curve now starts at 0 meters and factor 0, ends on 4 meters and factor 0.4.
- The second curve starts at 4 meters with factor 0.4 and ends with 10 meters at factor 1.

This was just for explaining the problem. The solution is quite simple: instead of using the *Sample Curve* node you can use the *Tangent* node and plug it directly into the *Align Euler to Vector* node. What I only would recommend is to increase the *Resolution Preview U* value in the *Curve Properties* to get a smoother alignment. And maybe, sometimes if the curve is a little bit twisted, it helps setting *Twist Method* to *Z-Up* instead of the default *Minimum*. But this also depends on which axis you choose to align to etc.

[image: align to curve tangent]

Comment: Oh my goodness, THAT is the answer.  
Apparently I don't have enough reputation here to upvote your answer, but you get massive appreciation.

Thank you so very much. :)

Comment: @RicoHolmes You're welcome, at first glance I didn't know what was wrong either until I remembered what the _Sample Curve_ node does...

Comment: Phrased much better than I was about to .. :) I'm still trying to reverse-engineer this [difference in behaviour between 2 methods of alignment](https://imgur.com/a/IXhrEJL)

Comment: @RobinBetts Not sure if I understand what you mean with different methods of alignment... _Align Euler to Vector_ is calculating the Euler rotation to align to a certain vector. Curve vertices are not rotated (apart from a tilt maybe). After converting with _Curve to Points_, the generated points are already rotated aligned to the curve, which is why you can use their _Rotation_ directly to align instances. The original curve's tangent and normal get lost, but the _Curve to Points_ node generates these vectors based on the points. These could also be used with _Align Euler to Vector_.

Comment: @Gordon ..zackerly. I would have thought the results should be the same? But the endpoints and penultimate points are rotated differently with the 2 methods.. some difference in interpolation...

Comment: @RobinBetts First of all, why exactly are you using 2 _Align Euler to Vector_ nodes, one with the _Tangent_ and one with _Normal_? And the second with Z as pivot? The latter tries to align the X of the object to the normal with restricting it to the local Z axis, which messes up the alignment. The other thing is, aligning twice to different vectors and axes cannot give the same result as using the rotation of the points, since they only have one rotation, which is (in the curve's direction) forward is +Z, to the right is +X and downwards is +Y, whereas the curve's tangent is aligned different.

Comment: @Gordon A fully-defined orientation *requires* 2  vector-determined  Euler rotations.  One  to align an axis, (here, Z) and once that axis is good, another to spin around it. This pair adopts the definition of XYZ used by to-points 'Rotation', and is, on the whole, near identical.. there just seems to be a difference in interpolation at the end-points. i.e I was just trying to figure out what  a point's 'rotation' is, if it isn't alignment to tangent and normal. It's no great shakes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136574/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-robin-betts).